# Can't install from zip after updating openelec

Tags: pi-3, openelec

I updated my openelec by doing so -
1. Format the SD card with [SD Card Formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/eula_mac/index.html) (Quick format)
2. Mount the new version .img file:
`sudo dd if=~/Downloads/OpenELEC-RPi2.arm-8.0.4.img of=/dev/rdisk4 bs=1m`

After that the openelec with new Kodi version loads. I can add a repository, but when I try to install add-on from .zip file it always fails with "invalid structure" error. This happens with whatever repository I try.

**Note:** Seems like I cannot format the SD card completely - After I format the SD card and load openelec, somehow it "remembers" my WiFi password. If I try to do a complete format (not a quick one) it always fails in the middle of the process.

Comment: If you are writing an `image` there is **no need** to format the card, as it will overwrite the partition table. I don't know about openelec, but the recent Raspbian have odd image sizes (not complete blocks) so the last block is not written. Etcher works OK with these. `dd conv=sync` is supposed to write the incomplete block, but you should note the blocks read and blocks written to see that they match.

Comment: @Milliways thanks for the Etcher tip I'll try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a defective SD card. Once I replaced the SD card everything started working again.